# swfobject.embedSWF not working?

Tags: javascript, html, swfobject

The following code embedding a Flash animation into an HTML document using SWFObject displays only the alternative content. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adding a Flash Movie</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.embedSWF("flash/bird.swf", "bird", "400", "300", "8.0.0");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bird">
            <p>An animation of a bird taking a shower</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Chrome, IE and Firefox all show just `An animation of a bird taking a shower`.

The code is [a sample](http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-09/adding-a-flash-movie.html) from the book [HTML & CSS: design and build websites](http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/).

Comment: Flash support is removed from lot of recent browsers. Please check browser compatibility before using it.

Comment: Flash support is not being removed from browsers. Rather, Flash is now enabled only after a 'ask to activate' popup. Unfortunately, swfobject does not function with this newer scheme.

Comment: Flash will reach its end of life in 2020, @Chris. Till then, browser vendors will gradually limit the use of Flash, till they ultimately drop its support completely. See the link I edited into your answer.

Comment: Loading `https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/` in a hidden `iframe` will prompt the user for permission to run Flash. See [Flash Roadmap for Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/flash-roadmap#TOC-Developer-Recommendations) and [the answer I got this info from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45841216/2157640).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SWFObject 2.2 no longer works properly. The [bug in SWFObject](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/issues/57) has already been reported on GitHub, but the library is unmaintained.

The new “HTML by default” Flash policy starting at Chrome 55 does not initialize the variables that SWFObject uses to detect whether Flash is installed. Specifically, `navigator.mimeTypes` no longer contains `application/x-shockwave-flash`, unless Flash is enabled by the user. Other browsers have similar issues related to the [click-to-run activation scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Flash_Activation:_Browser_Comparison) introduced as part of [Flash’es end of life](https://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2017/07/adobe-flash-update.html).

At this time, the best course of action may be to simply use `<object>` to embed Flash. For example:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="app.swf">
    <param name='movie' value="app.swf"/>
    <param name='bgcolor' value="#999999"/>
    <param name='FlashVars' value="var1=Hello&var2=Goodbye" />
    <param name='allowscriptaccess' value="sameDomain"/>
</object>
```

Note that (1) the .swf is specified in two places (2) only the `movie` param is required; the other params are shown here as an example of what is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome's since version 55 does not initialize the variables that swfobject needs to detect if Flash is installed.
You can apply primitive patch to swfobject js to skip hasPlayerVersion check:

```
-       if (hasPlayerVersion(swfVersionStr)) { // create SWF
+       try {  // create SWF
            var obj = createSWF(att, par, replaceElemIdStr);
            if (att.id == replaceElemIdStr) {
                setVisibility(replaceElemIdStr, true);
            }
            callbackObj.success = true;
            callbackObj.ref = obj;
-       }
-       else if (xiSwfUrlStr && canExpressInstall()) { // show Adobe Express Install
-           att.data = xiSwfUrlStr;
-           showExpressInstall(att, par, replaceElemIdStr, callbackFn);
-           return;
-       }
-       else { // show alternative content
+       } catch (e) {  // show alternative content
            setVisibility(replaceElemIdStr, true);
        }
```

Comment: Might as well change `hasPlayerVersion()` to return true all the time?

Comment: No, because it will not show replaceElemIdStr in old browsers