# website slider is not working on Google Chrome and Mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, html, slider, swfobject

Kindly help me, my website slider is not working on Google Chrome and Mozilla firefox. Allthough it is working in Internet Explorer 11. this website is 4 years old. Slider was made 4 years ago.

[my website link](http://www.drmohinderdentalclinic.com)

Following is the HTML and javascript code of website slider.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var flashvars = {};
      flashvars.cssSource = "css/piecemaker.css";
      flashvars.xmlSource = "xml/piecemaker.xml";  
      var params = {};
      params.play = "true";
      params.menu = "false";
      params.scale = "showall";
      params.wmode = "transparent";
      params.allowfullscreen = "true";
      params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
      params.allownetworking = "all";
   
      swfobject.embedSWF('flash/piecemaker.swf', 'piecemaker', '942', '300', '10', null, flashvars,    
      params, null);      
</script>
```

```html
 <!-- Slider Area Starts-->
    <div id="slider">          
     <div id="piecemaker">
        <p>Slider works here.</p>
     </div>             
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a flash player installed and not blocked in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880942/swfobject-embedswf-not-working-in-chrome maybe...

Comment: chrome and firefox have flash disabled by default (dont pin me down since wich version but for quite a time now), switching to a javascript or css slider could help there

Answer (score 0):

Your slider is in Flash. This is a bit outdated now - for example some browsers disable flash by default and it isn't supported on ios (iPhone/iPad). You can easily re-create this slider using a HTML5 slider - try WOW jquery slider. Once you create it, you can just add an iframe (WOW creates it for you) in place of your existing flash slider.

Hope this helps