# SWFObject not being displayed in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash, swfobject

Our code is (using SWFObject v2.2):

```
function showGauge( wrapper, score, isBig )
{
var flashvars = { score: score };
var params = { allowscriptaccess: "always" };

var attributes = { wmode: "transparent" };
var size = 175;

if( isBig )
{
    size = 225;
}

swfobject.embedSWF( "<?php echo Routing::base(); ?>flash/sparc.swf", wrapper, size, size, "10.3.0", "<?php echo Routing::base(); ?>flash/expressInstall.swf", 
                    flashvars, params, attributes );

$( '#' + wrapper ).parent().find( '.sparcScoreLabel' ).show();
}
```

We have a website with SWFObject embeding flash (shown above) and it was always working perfectly on all browsers, but it seems that recently it stopped working on Chrome - I think it used to be played automaticaly like on all other browsers, but Google changed policy for this and now every flash needs to be clicked on played OR an option "flash -> allow" chosen from menu next to the URL (on the left side where the padlock icon is). However with SWFObject there is nothing even visible to be clicked and most users won't even notice that there should be flash animation to see and they won't bother to click "Flash -> allow" in Chrome settings for the website. We want to our flash to be played automaticly on Chrome just like on every other browser, even without need to click anything. How can we force Chrome to play flash automaticaly ? Or do I need to change SWFObject to simple

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> ... </object>
```

tag and live with the fact that it won't be fully automatic on Chrome ?

Comment: Are you sure PHP processes its **<?php .. ?>** normally, and the URL to SWF is correct?

Answer (score 0):

swfobject no longer works with Chrome.

Check this other question for a solution:
[swfobject.embedSWF not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880942/swfobject-embedswf-not-working/41303952#41303952)