# I need help to add a swf in my site - swfobject

Tags: javascript, html, flash, swfobject

I need some help to implement swfobject.

I add this to my page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" src_type="url" />
```

then I create a div with ID: **flash-banner**

```
<div id="flash-banner"></div>
```

and this is how I try to call the swfobject

```
<script>
var flash = document.getElementById("#flash-banner");
swfobject.embedSWF("pub/media/wysiwyg/welcome.swf", flash, 300, 120, 10);
</script>
```

I do something wrong? What is not good here?

Thank you

Comment: I mean… your problem is that you're using Flash for new development. It's generally deprecated, won't run by default in some browsers, won't run _at all_ on mobile browsers, and will be end-of-lifed by Adobe in 2020.

Comment: I know this but need to be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, no one should be doing anything new with Flash these days - it's a dead end technology (I don't have it installed in any of my browsers, on any platform, for example). But the technical problem is that embedSWF wants the *name* of the ID as a string, but document.getElementByID returns the *object*, not its name. So, what you want is simply:

```
<script>
swfobject.embedSWF("pub/media/wysiwyg/welcome.swf", "flash-banner", "300", "120", "10");
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much, and one thing please if you can help me, is there any way to have the width: 100% ?

Comment: Just quote the attributes, like "100%". Editing my response - the pixel and version values should be quoted, too.

Comment: If you're doing any "filling," you'll want to tell embedSWF how to do the scaling. This page should help: http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/100-width-and-height-in-browser/

Answer (score 0):

swfobject should be avoided because it no longer works in Chrome.

More details in this answer: [swfobject.embedSWF not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880942/swfobject-embedswf-not-working/41303952#41303952)