# Problems with Adobe Flash Player blocking HTTP Response

Tags: java, http, flash, servlets

I have a project that I have been working on part - time and it is now due to be submitted.  I am connected to an external plc via ethernet and trying to retrieve data from the device using HTTP requests.  I had this working, with the data being received back in XML format and I was able to parse this data and submit it to a database.

I am only now submitting the project and what was working is no longer working!! Instead of getting the data back in XML format I am getting a message to install Adobe Flash Player.  On investigating the problem, Google and the other browsers have disabled some of the abilities of how to control how the flash player can be used.  Previously when I had the program running I had to enable flash player on all sites and this worked.  Now I am only allowed to enable it on specified sites and no matter what option I input I am still getting the same error.

In relation to the HTTP connection I am getting a code 200 response which shows that the connection is working but I cannot get back the data that I was always getting.

Has anyone else had this problem since Chrome has changed its policy?  I have tried other browsers but the same problem.  I have tried back tracking with an older version of Chrome but have only been able to get a .exe file to run individually rather than installed on the computer so Netbeans doesn't recognise it.  I have tried Firefox and their extended version which is meant to allow for these issues until March/April 2018 but I am getting the same problem with this also.

Any insight or help would be appreciated.

This is the server information

[image: Server Response]

This is the result from the request for information

```
'<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
    <!-- 
    Smart developers always View Source. 

    This application was built using Apache Flex, an open source framework
    for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
    Flash Player or to desktops and mobile phones via Adobe AIR. 

    Learn more about Flex at http://flex.apache.org 
    // -->
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="google" value="notranslate" />         
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!-- Include CSS to eliminate any default margins/padding and set the height of the html element and 
             the body element to 100%, because Firefox, or any Gecko based browser, interprets percentage as 
             the percentage of the height of its parent container, which has to be set explicitly.  Fix for
             Firefox 3.6 focus border issues.  Initially, don't display flashContent div so it won't show 
             if JavaScript disabled.
        -->
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
            html, body  { height:100%; }
            body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:auto; text-align:center; 
                   background-color: #ffffff; }   
            object:focus { outline:none; }
            #flashContent { display:none; }
        </style>

        <!-- Enable Browser History by replacing useBrowserHistory tokens with two hyphens -->
        <!-- BEGIN Browser History required section -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history/history.js"></script>
        <!-- END Browser History required section -->  

        <script type="text/javascript" src="451swfob.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. 
            var swfVersionStr = "12.0.0";
            // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. 
            var xiSwfUrlStr = "451inst.swf";//"expressInstall.swf";
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            params.quality = "high";
            params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
            params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
            params.allowfullscreen = "true";
            var attributes = {};
            attributes.id = "WebApp";
            attributes.name = "WebApp";
            attributes.align = "middle";
            swfobject.embedSWF(
                "WebApp.swf", "flashContent", 
                "100%", "100%", 
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                flashvars, params, attributes);
            // JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object.
            swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- SWFObject's dynamic embed method replaces this alternative HTML content with Flash content when enough 
             JavaScript and Flash plug-in support is available. The div is initially hidden so that it doesn't show
             when JavaScript is disabled.
        -->
        <div id="flashContent">
            <p>
                To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 
                12.0.0 or greater is installed. 
            </p>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://"); 
                document.write("<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='" 
                                + pageHost + "www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a>" ); 
            </script> 
        </div>

        <noscript>
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="WebApp">
                <param name="movie" value="WebApp.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="WebApp.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
                    <p> 
                        Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or Adobe Flash Player version
                        12.0.0 or greater is not installed.
                    </p>
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </noscript>     
   </body>
</html>`
```

This is basically telling me to install Adobe Flash Player as far as I can see which is already done!

The following is code from the servlet.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.*;



/**
 *
 * @author ******
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/DeviceReadDateTime"})
public class DanfossDeviceReadDateTime extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */



       String userName;
       String userPassword;
       String siteAddress;
       String tagReference;
       String reportType;
       String danfossResponseXMLReturned;
       String danfossReadDateTimeYear;
       String danfossReadDateTimeMonth;
       String danfossReadDateTimeDay;
       String danfossReadDateTimeHour;
       String danfossReadDateTimeMinute;
       String danfossReadDateTimeSecond;
       String danfossReadDateTimeEpoch;
       String danfossReadDateTimeTimeZone;
       String danfossReadDateTimeDayLightSavings;

       Connection conn;
       PreparedStatement prepStat;
       Statement stat;
       ResultSet rs = null;

    /**
     *
     * @throws ServletException
     */

       @Override
       public void init() throws ServletException
       {

        String connectionUrl ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:***;" +
                   "databaseName=*******************;user=**;password=*****";




           try{

               // establishing the connection

              Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
              conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);



               System.out.println("You are connected to SQLServer 2014");



         //      stat = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

             // retrieve data

     /*   Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select * from danfossDateTime");
        while(rs1.next()){
            danfossReadDateTimeYear = rs1.getString(1);
            danfossReadDateTimeMonth = rs1.getString(2);
            danfossReadDateTimeDay = rs1.getString(3);
            danfossReadDateTimeHour = rs1.getString(4);    
            danfossReadDateTimeMinute = rs1.getString(5);
            danfossReadDateTimeSecond = rs1.getString(6);
            danfossReadDateTimeEpoch = rs1.getString(7);
            danfossReadDateTimeTimeZone = rs1.getString(8);
            danfossReadDateTimeDayLightSavings = rs1.getString(9);


            System.out.println("danfossReadDateTimeYear = " + danfossReadDateTimeYear + "\n"
                    + "danfossReadDateTimeMonth = " + danfossReadDateTimeMonth + "\n"
                    + "danfossReadDateTimeDay = " + danfossReadDateTimeDay
             + "danfossReadDateTimeHour = " + danfossReadDateTimeHour + "\n"
             + "danfossReadDateTimeMinute = " + danfossReadDateTimeMinute + "\n"
             + "danfossReadDateTimeSecond = " + danfossReadDateTimeSecond + "\n"
             + "danfossReadDateTimeEpoch = " + danfossReadDateTimeEpoch + "\n"
             + "danfossReadDateTimeTimeZone = " + danfossReadDateTimeTimeZone + "\n"
             + "danfossReadDateTimeDayLightSavings = " + danfossReadDateTimeDayLightSavings + "\n");
        }

         System.out.println("Data retrieved from MS SQL");

       */
       }   catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(DanfossDeviceReadDateTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }

     }// end of init method// end of init method// end of init method// end of init method





    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        Cookie cookie = null;
        Cookie cookiesArray[] = null;

        //get an array of cookies associated with this domain
        cookiesArray = request.getCookies();

        if(cookiesArray != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<cookiesArray.length; i++)
            {
                cookie = cookiesArray[i];

                switch (cookie.getName()) {
                    case "userName":
                        userName = cookie.getValue();
                        break;
                    case "userPassword":
                        userPassword = cookie.getValue();
                        break;
                    case "siteAddress":
                        siteAddress = cookie.getValue();
                        siteAddress = ("http:\\").concat(siteAddress);
                        break;
                }

            }
        }




        //Code requesting that data from the danfoss unit

        XPath path;



        String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n\r\n<cmd action=\"read_date_time\" node =\"1\"/>\r\n\r\n";

       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream");

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, xmlString);

        Request danfossRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .url(siteAddress)
            .post(body)
            .build();

         System.out.println("danfossRequest = " + danfossRequest);

        Response danfossResponse = client.newCall(danfossRequest).execute();

        System.out.println("danfossResponse = " + danfossResponse);




        // converting string to xml and parsing

        danfossResponseXMLReturned = danfossResponse.body().string();
         System.out.println("danfossResponseXMLReturned = " + danfossResponseXMLReturned);

        XMLReader parser;

        try {

            Document dbfactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(danfossResponseXMLReturned.getBytes("utf-8"))));
            XPathFactory xpfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            path = xpfactory.newXPath();



            danfossReadDateTimeYear = path.evaluate("/resp/year", dbfactory);
            danfossReadDateTimeMonth = path.evaluate("/resp/month", dbfactory);
            danfossReadDateTimeDay = path.evaluate("/resp/day", dbfactory);
            danfossReadDateTimeHour = path.evaluate("/resp/hour", dbfactory);
            danfossReadDateTimeMinute = path.evaluate("/resp/minute", dbfactory);
            danfossReadDateTimeSecond = path.evaluate("/resp/second", dbfactory);
            danfossReadDateTimeEpoch = path.evaluate("/resp/epoch", dbfactory);
            danfossReadDateTimeTimeZone = path.evaluate("/resp/timezone", dbfactory);
            danfossReadDateTimeDayLightSavings = path.evaluate("/resp/daylightsavings", dbfactory);

            //print results
            System.out.println("danfossReadDateTimeYear = " + danfossReadDateTimeYear);
            System.out.println("danfossReadDateTimeMonth = " + danfossReadDateTimeMonth);

        } catch (FactoryConfigurationError err) {
            System.err.println ("can't create JAXP SAXParserFactory, "
            + err.getMessage ());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException err) {
            System.err.println ("can't create XMLReader with namespaces, "
            + err.getMessage ());
        } catch (SAXException err) {
            System.err.println ("Hmm, SAXException, " + err.getMessage ());
        }  catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(DanfossDeviceReadDevices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }


        System.out.println(danfossReadDateTimeYear);
        System.out.println(danfossReadDateTimeMonth);
        System.out.println(danfossReadDateTimeDay);
        System.out.println(danfossReadDateTimeHour);
        System.out.println(danfossReadDateTimeMinute);
        System.out.println(danfossReadDateTimeSecond);
        System.out.println(danfossReadDateTimeEpoch);
        System.out.println(danfossReadDateTimeTimeZone);
        System.out.println(danfossReadDateTimeDayLightSavings);

// submit data to database

    /*    try{
            String query = "INSERT INTO danfossDateTime VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            prepStat = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);
            prepStat.setString(1,danfossReadDateTimeYear);
            prepStat.setString(2,danfossReadDateTimeMonth);
            prepStat.setString(3,danfossReadDateTimeDay);
            prepStat.setString(4,danfossReadDateTimeHour);
            prepStat.setString(5,danfossReadDateTimeMinute);
            prepStat.setString(6,danfossReadDateTimeSecond);
            prepStat.setString(7,danfossReadDateTimeEpoch);
            prepStat.setString(8,danfossReadDateTimeTimeZone);
            prepStat.setString(9,danfossReadDateTimeDayLightSavings);
            prepStat.executeUpdate();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
   */
    //html page output


        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
           // out = response.getWriter();
            String title = "***";
            String docType = "<!doctype html>";
            out.println(docType + "<html>\n" +

"<head>\n" +
"    <title>***</title>\n" +
"    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"***RemoteSiteDataCheckerCSS2.css\"/>\n" +
"</head>\n" +
"<body>\n" +
"    \n" +
"    \n" +
"    <section id=\"logo\">\n" +
"        <!-- Introduction on the company -->\n" +
"        <header>\n" +
"        <center><h1>**************</h1></center>\n" +
"    \n" +
"        <center><h3>Remote Site Data Checker</h3></center>\n" +
"        </header>\n" +
"    </section>\n" +
"    \n" +
"    \n" +
"     \n" +
"    <section>\n" +
"        <form action=\"SubmitTestData\" method=\"POST\">\n" +
"            <label>User Name</label> <input type=\"text\" name=\"userName\" value=\"" + userName + "\">\n" +
"            <br>\n" +
"            <label>Password</label> <input type=\"password\" name=\"userPassword\" value=\"" + userPassword + "\">\n" +
"            <br>\n" +
"            <label>Site Address</label> <input type=\"text\" name=\"siteAddress\" value=\"" + siteAddress + "\">\n" +
"            <br>\n" +
"            <label></label><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit Test Data\"/>\n" +
"             \n" +
"        </form>\n" +
"    </section>   \n" +
"    \n" +
"    <section>\n" +
"       <form>\n" +
"        <label>Results:</label>\n" +
"        \n" +
"        <textarea name=\"resultsTextBox\" rows=\"10\" cols=\"80\" wrap=\"hard\">\n" +
"            Results now here...\n" + danfossResponseXMLReturned +
"         \nFrom XML Dom BUilder - year =   "  + danfossReadDateTimeYear  +
"         \nFrom XML Dom BUilder - month =   "  +  danfossReadDateTimeMonth +
"         \nFrom XML Dom BUilder - day =   "  +             danfossReadDateTimeDay  +
"         \nFrom XML Dom BUilder - hour =   "  +            danfossReadDateTimeHour +
"         \nFrom XML Dom BUilder - minute =   "  +             danfossReadDateTimeMinute +
"         \nFrom XML Dom BUilder - second =   "  +             danfossReadDateTimeSecond +
"         \nFrom XML Dom BUilder - epoch =   "  +             danfossReadDateTimeEpoch +
"         \nFrom XML Dom BUilder - timezone =   "  +             danfossReadDateTimeTimeZone +
"         \nFrom XML Dom BUilder - daylightsavings =   "  +             danfossReadDateTimeDayLightSavings +

"        </textarea>\n" +
"        </form>\n" +
"    </section>   \n" +
"                    \n<section>\n" +
"        <button onclick=\"location.href='index.html'\">Home Page</button>\n" +
"        <button onclick=\"location.href='DanfossDeviceHome.html'\">Generate New Report</button>\n" +
"        \n" +
"    </section>" +

"                \n" +
"    <footer>\n" +
"        <!-- Footer -->\n" +
"        <hr>\n" +
"   \n" +
"       <p>**********************</p>\n" +
"    </footer>\n" +
" \n" +
"</body>\n" +
"</html>\n" +
"\n");





    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
           try {
               processRequest(request, response);
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(DanfossDeviceReadDateTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
           try {
               processRequest(request, response);
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(DanfossDeviceReadDateTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: This really looks like one of those fake flash update pages.  Are you confident that the server you're requesting from is ok?

Comment: swfobject does not work with Chrome anymore. Use <object> instead. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880942/swfobject-embedswf-not-working/41303952#41303952).Also, Chrome may prompt you about using Flash, but should not prompt you to install/update Flash since it takes care of that automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I have tried the steps to reduce fake flash updates and this hasn't helped stdunbar,  I am still getting the same problem.  I have also looking into your comments Chris and the swfobject is coming back from the information being read back by the http response - I don't have that anywhere in my own code.  If you have any other ideas I would appreciate it!