# Flash Object in Chrome 65 doesn't 'start'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash

On Chrome 65 (currently in Beta as of this posting) one of my flash objects (injected using swfobject 2.3) doesn't 'start'.

I can see it on the page, and I can right click on it. When I right click I can choose "Run this plug-in" or "Hide this plug-in"

"Hide this plug-in" simply applies 'display:none'

"Run this plug-in" has no noticeable effect.

Hovering over the plugin adds the title "Adobe Flash Player"

And there are no console errors thrown.

Here's the DOM:

```
<object id="device-setup-bandwidth-checker" width="366" height="272" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/static/bwchecker/BandwidthChecker.swf?v=3459" style="/* display: none; */">
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
  <param name="flashvars" value="readyCallback=bandwidthChecker.setSwfReady&amp;downstreamCallback=bandwidthChecker.processDownstreamResult&amp;downstreamUrl=rtmp://x.x.x.x/bwcheck&amp;upstreamCallback=bandwidthChecker.processUpstreamResult&amp;upstreamUrl=rtmp://x.x.x.x/upbwcheck">
</object>
```

(I have replaced the ip with x.x.x.x)

Note: I have tested this same feature of Firefox and Safari and it works fine on both of those platforms.

Answer (score 0):

swfobject no longer works with Chrome.

More details in the answer to this question: [swfobject.embedSWF not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880942/swfobject-embedswf-not-working/41303952#41303952)