# Page is showing javascript logs, but it's not loading my swf

Tags: javascript, html, swfobject

Вell, I tried to debug my javascript code and that's working бut my code won't work. It's an existing code.

Сcreen of debug:

[image]

what do I wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>CMS - Game</title>
<script src="/Templates/template1/client/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Templates/template1/client/js/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Templates/template1/client/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Templates/template1/client/js/flashclient.js"></script>
<script src="/Templates/template1/client/js/flash_detect_min.js"></script>
<script src="/Templates/template1/client/js/client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="client-ui">
        <div id="client" style='position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; overflow:hidden; height:100%; width:100%;'></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var Client = new SWFObject("http://localhost/swf/", "client", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0");
        Client.addVariable("client.allow.cross.domain", "0");
        Client.addVariable("client.notify.cross.domain", "1");
        Client.addVariable("connection.info.host", "127.0.0.1");
        Client.addVariable("connection.info.port", "30000");
        Client.addVariable("site.url", "http://localhost/");
        Client.addVariable("url.prefix", "http://localhost/");
        Client.addVariable("client.reload.url", "http://localhost/me");
        Client.addVariable("client.fatal.error.url", "http://localhost/me");
        Client.addVariable("client.connection.failed.url", "http://localhost/me");
        Client.addVariable("external.override.texts.txt", "http://localhost/swf/gamedata/override/external_flash_override_texts.txt");
        Client.addVariable("external.override.variables.txt", "http://localhost/swf/gamedata/override/external_override_variables.txt");
        Client.addVariable("external.variables.txt", "http://localhost/swf/gamedata/external_variables.txt");
        Client.addVariable("external.texts.txt", "http://localhost/swf/gamedata/external_flash_texts.txt");
        Client.addVariable("external.figurepartlist.txt", "http://localhost/swf/gamedata/figuredata.xml");
        Client.addVariable("flash.dynamic.avatar.download.configuration", "http://localhost/swf/gamedata/figuremap.xml");
        Client.addVariable("productdata.load.url", "http://localhost/swf/gamedata/productdata.txt");
        Client.addVariable("furnidata.load.url", "http://localhost/swf/gamedata/furnidata.xml");
        Client.addVariable("use.sso.ticket", "1");
        Client.addVariable("sso.ticket", "hdSlLTPFI2dmP0rR4Yz43rs4B-SSO");
        Client.addVariable("processlog.enabled", "0");
        Client.addVariable("client.starting", "CMS Hotel is aan het laden...");
        Client.addVariable("flash.client.url", "http://localhost/swf/");
        Client.addVariable("flash.client.origin", "popup");
        Client.addVariable("nux.lobbies.enabled", "true");
        Client.addVariable("country_code", "NL");
        Client.addParam('base', 'http://localhost/swf/');
        Client.addParam('allowScriptAccess', 'always');
        Client.addParam('menu', false);
        Client.addParam('wmode', "opaque");
        Client.write('client');

        FlashExternalInterface.signoutUrl = "http://localhost/logout";
    </script>
```

what I want is loading a client using SWF.

Comment: Maybe you have to allow flash in your browser?

Comment: Might want to discontinue use of Flash as it will cease to be viable by next year: https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/news/450423574/Adobes-Flash-end-of-life-scheduled-finally-for-2020

Comment: I allowed flash in my browser.. but still nothing

Comment: SWFObject is obsolete and no longer works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41303952/960857