# FLV won't play through OSplayer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to play a simple FLV video using the OSPlayer but the video doesn't appear on the page at all.

Also ran into this problem previously when i tried to embed a swf game. It didn't appear at all.

Everything is hosted on my own PC

Disclaimer:New to coding
(I'm following Jon Ducketts HTML + CSS book)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flash video</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../flash/OSFlvPlayer_v4.2/OSplayer.swf"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var flashvars = {};
      var params = {movie:"../flash/20051210-w50s.flv"};
      swfobject.embedSWF("../flash/OSFlvPlayer_v4.2/OSplayer.swf", "race", "400", "400", "8.0.0",
       "flashvars", "params");</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="race"><p>Granny race</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Simply displays "Granny race" and no video.

Comment: try adding your script tag after the 'div' inside your 'body'

Comment: Didn't seem to work, according to the book it should all be in the head too.

Comment: maybe this helps you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880942/swfobject-embedswf-not-working

Comment: also, is this book updated? i saw that it first came out in 2011, which isn't really up to date anymore

Comment: Ah i see, think you might be right. Any updated books you recommend? I plan to learn HTML/CSS then Javascript. Then move into backend with python possibly.

Comment: unfortunately, not really, i learned most of html + css throught online tutorials / mdn and such.

Comment: No worries, appreciate your help. I'll have a look at MDN.